# Appropriate response to fellowship award notice via email

Tags: etiquette, email

I received an email notifying that my colleague and I have been awarded a fellowship, sent by an administrator but signed by the director of the programme which is a professor. The institution in based in the US. The professor and another administrator are copied in that email. The only instruction in the email was to contact an administrator notifying them of my acceptance.

What is the appropriate response? Should I reply to the initial email thanking for the fellowship in addition to writing the administrator? Should I include the director of the programme?

Being based in northern Europe, my initial impression is that a "thank you" email sent to everyone's mailbox would be an annoyance, but I'm completely ignorant of etiquette in American academia. Would a lack of a thank you email be seen as a lack of gratitude?

Comment: How much are they paying you?  And are you a PhD student?

Comment: It is a very small amount (about 1000 dollars) that works as a seed money for establishing further cooperation. They will also offer training and media coaching, which also adds to their costs.

Comment: And I'm not a PhD student.

Comment: For that little money, I would not give it thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't just reply-all to such an email, letting everyone know of your decision at the same time. Those who don't need the information can just ignore the mail. And include a thank-you with the acceptance.

If you decline it, then the same would apply, with "thank you, but ..." for the award.